# Id variable in order within another id variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I already have an id variable (patient_id), and I have multiple observations per id (blood_pressure), but I want a new id variable containing 1 for the first id, 2 for the second, and so on within each patient_id. Please see my interested data format in the link. How can I generate “order” variable using R? I want something like this:

[image: data format]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `dplyr`. First, I create a toy data frame. (For future questions, it's easier for us if you post copy-and-pasteable data rather than an image. `dput` is useful for this.)

```
df <- data.frame(patient_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                 blood_pressure = sample(90:134, 12, replace = TRUE))
```

which looks like this:

```
#    patient_id blood_pressure
# 1           1            130
# 2           1            130
# 3           1            128
# 4           2            109
# 5           2             91
# 6           3             95
# 7           3            129
# 8           4            134
# 9           4            116
# 10          4            101
# 11          4            131
# 12          4            112
```

Next, I load the required library.

```
library(dplyr)
```

Then, I group by `patient_id`, add a variable called `order` using the `mutate` function, which is the row number within each group given by the `row_number` function, and finally `ungroup` the result.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(patient_id) %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup
```

giving,

```
#    patient_id blood_pressure order
#         <dbl>          <int> <int>
# 1          1            130     1
# 2          1            130     2
# 3          1            128     3
# 4          2            109     1
# 5          2             91     2
# 6          3             95     1
# 7          3            129     2
# 8          4            134     1
# 9          4            116     2
# 10         4            101     3
# 11         4            131     4
# 12         4            112     5
```

Comment: @MiladNazarzadeh Please select this as the answer.